# Ensuring ElasticSearch is in Sync with Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm considering a daily script to do the following, in order to account for any situations where there was a problem with updates on the ES server (I don't yet have a high-availability setup and even so, it's still probably a good practice in a situation where data is being duplicated between DB and ES). Before putting this script together, I thought I'd check if I'm going about this the right way, and whether there are any libraries or techniques I should use.

The script will simply retrieve all IDs from the database and all IDs from ElasticSearch, where `created_at < current_time` (a snapshot of the current time, since it's a moving target as the script runs). It will then add and remove to Elastic search based on the differences between these  IDs sets.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my question, this is not the best approach.

A simpler, if more resource-intensive, approach is to re-build the entire index periodically. Of course, this is difficult to do in production as it would cause minutes or hours of downtime, so the trick is to rebuild a new index and switch to using that. In ElasticSearch, you can't rename an index, but you can use aliases.

There's a discussion of the approach [here](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/62) and a rake task for Tire users [here](https://gist.github.com/3751744).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) plugin. This plugin is fairly stable and can be used to sync data between ES and database.

Comment: I already have a mapping in Ruby via Tire, so unless there was a plugin that did it automatically, there's not much reason to switch over to a Java solution.

Comment: You just need to install this plugin and map the DB like this query

`curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from orders"
    }
}' `

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure the types will be mapped the same way Tire maps them though.